# Get all possible part-of-speech tags for a word using NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, part-of-speech

Some words can have more than one possible part of speech (pos) tag.
E.g. 'Stick' is both a noun and a verb.

The pos taggers in NLTK try to guess the correct tag based on context and return only the 1 guess. How can I instead get a list of all possible tags for any given word?

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

No, not for the default `pos_tag` function.

---

## In Long

For the default `pos_tag` function it's not possible.

The default `pos_tag` function is from the `AveragedPerceptron` object that uses the `predict()` function to get the most probable tag: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tag/perceptron.py#L48

The function returns the argmax from the list of probable tags:

```
def predict(self, features):
    '''Dot-product the features and current weights and return the best label.'''
    scores = defaultdict(float)
    for feat, value in features.items():
        if feat not in self.weights or value == 0:
            continue
        weights = self.weights[feat]
        for label, weight in weights.items():
            scores[label] += value * weight
    # Do a secondary alphabetic sort, for stability
    return max(self.classes, key=lambda label: (scores[label], label))
```

Effectively, if you change the code you code get the score of every possible tag by letting it return `self.classes`.

But because the features used in `tag()` requires the previous two tags as features https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tag/perceptron.py#L156

```
def tag(self, tokens):
    '''
    Tag tokenized sentences.
    :params tokens: list of word
    :type tokens: list(str)
    '''
    prev, prev2 = self.START
    output = []

    context = self.START + [self.normalize(w) for w in tokens] + self.END
    for i, word in enumerate(tokens):
        tag = self.tagdict.get(word)
        if not tag:
            features = self._get_features(i, word, context, prev, prev2)
            tag = self.model.predict(features)
        output.append((word, tag))
        prev2 = prev
        prev = tag

    return output
```

The task of returning n-best tags would have to change the simple one-best "greedy" nature of the tagger to something that requires a beam.

Comment: Thank you @alvas for the insight. One approximate way to check all different POS tags a word has is to download the specific wordnet version database from https://wordnet.princeton.edu/download and search the word. Or just check wordnet online: http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn for newest version.

Comment: Wordnet is exhaustive.